# Add a token to Cloud Endpoints HTTP requests

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an API working with Cloud Endpoints and I added its generated client library to my Android app.

However I don't know how to add my auth token to my requests. For now, here is the only HTTP request I know how to send:

```
DrinkEndpoint.Builder builder = new DrinkEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),new GsonFactory(), null);
            DrinkEndpoint service = builder.build();
            Drink drink = new Drink();
            drink.setName(params[0]);
            response = service.insertDrink(drink).execute();
```

So my question is: how to modify this code to add my auth token:
1) in the body of the POST request
2) or in the authorization header

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `GoogleAccountCredential` as the last argument

```
new DrinkEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), googleAccountCredential);
```

Example how to build the credentials with G+ scope:

```
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(app)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
        .build();

GoogleAccountCredential googleAccountCredential =
     GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context, "server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID);
     googleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(userEmail);
```

The `WEB_CLIENT_ID` comes from the Google Developers Console and it tight to your project. If you don't have one you can create it in the console (You project -> APIs & auth -> Credentials).

Comment: Ok that will be useful, thank you. Could you also tell me how to add another object to my HTTP request? (e.g. a non-google token or any other kind of string) For now I just know how to add an instance of my entity, or a google token.

Comment: @Kritias Unfortunately I don't know how to do this. This should be another question, maybe somebody will help you in this matter.